# writing numbers and strings to a file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io

I've got a node.js app where I'm trying to read and write numbers and stings to files.

I'm currently writing

```
fs.writeFileSync(myPath, value);
```

where value can be either a number or a string.

When I read the file

```
fs.readFileSync(myPath,'utf-8');
```

I get the file as a string. I'm hoping there is a way for me to read the file, without needing to specify if the contents of the file are a number or a string. Is this possible?

The way around it, I suspect, is to try to convert the string to a number and see if it fails, but I'm hoping there is a better way. I'm happy to use `fs.writeStream/fs.readStream` with buffers (actually preferrable), but I'm not sure exactly what the best path here is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the encoding option is specified then readFileSync returns a string.
Otherwise it returns a buffer.

So say the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options)

To read a buffer you'd normally use `.toString('utf8')` in Node, so that gets you nowhere.
In other words, reading a file will return a string in Node, and not a valid integer, but you can check if the string is a number, it's as easy as calling `isNaN`

```
var is_number = !isNaN(file_string);
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be something nicer, but I could do `return isNaN(file_output) ? file_output : parseInt(file_output)`

Comment: Yes you could, remember the radix in parseInt!